# Android TransactionTooLargeException using Navigation

Tags: android, navigation

My App is crashing with `TransactionTooLargeException` Exception.
I've read a lot about on Google and StackOverflow but nothing works.
I'm not using arguments to pass data to other Fragments.
ViewModel are not storing huge data.

I've only one Activity, and I'm using `Navigation` to display Fragments.
I'm also using `Dagger2`, `ViewBinding` and `ViewModel`.

With tool `toolargetool` I found where the memory is increasing when I'm navigating :

```
NavHostFragment.onSaveInstanceState()
```

Every time the app changes fragment displayed, the size increase.
When app goes to background and size is too large, app crashes.

**EDIT**
Solution : to prevent this crash I used `navController?.popBackStack()`

Comment: You save too much in onSaveInstanceState(). But we dont know what you save..

Comment: It's Bundle navState = mNavController.saveState(); outState.putBundle(KEY_NAV_CONTROLLER_STATE, navState); which seems to be problematic in my case. Can I flush it ?